# Copying images from multiple folders into one folders

Tags: c, posix, dirent.h

I have a folder and there are multiple folders in it and each folder contain many photos, for example, I have a folder `2018` and folder `2018` contain `11` more folders and all those 11 folders contain some amount of images, all are of the same format .jpg. I want to copy all those images from different folders into one folder.

I have tried the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#define MAX 1024

int main()
{
    char    arSrcPath[]    = "/home/mpe4/Src";    /*Source directory path*/
    char    arDestPath[]    = "/home/mpe4/Dest";    /*dest directory path*/
    struct    dirent* spnDirPtr;    /* struct dirent to store all files*/

    DIR* pnOpenDir = NULL;    /*DIR Pointer to open Dir*/
    DIR* pnReadDir = NULL;    /*DIR POinter to read directory*/

    pnOpenDir = opendir(arSrcPath); 

    if(!pnOpenDir)
    printf("\n ERROR! Directory can not be open");

    else
    {    
    int nErrNo = 0;
    while(spnDirPtr = readdir(pnOpenDir))
    {
        if(nErrNo == 0)
        nErrNo = errno;
        printf("\n Now writing %s file...",spnDirPtr->d_name);

        printf("\n dest file name = %s/%s\n", arDestPath, spnDirPtr->d_name);

        struct stat st_buf;
        stat(spnDirPtr->d_name, &st_buf);
        if (S_ISDIR (st_buf.st_mode))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (S_ISREG (st_buf.st_mode))
        {
            FILE* pnReadFile = fopen(spnDirPtr->d_name,"r");

            if(pnReadFile)
            {
                printf("\n Now reading %s file...",spnDirPtr->d_name);

                char strDestFileName[MAX] = {0};
                sprintf(strDestFileName, "%s/%s", arDestPath, spnDirPtr->d_name);
                printf("\n dest file name = %s\n", strDestFileName);

                FILE* pnWriteFile  = fopen(strDestFileName, "w");    /*File Pointer to write in file*/
                if(pnWriteFile)
                {
                    char buffer[MAX] = {0};    /*Buffer to store files content*/

                        while(fgets(buffer, MAX, pnReadFile))
                        {
                            fputs(buffer, pnWriteFile);
                        }
                    fclose(pnWriteFile);
                }
            else
            {
                printf("\n Unable to open file %s", strDestFileName);
            }
            fclose(pnReadFile);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\nERROR! File Could not be open for reading");
    }
    }
    }
    if(nErrNo != errno)
        printf ("\nERROR Occurred!\n");
    else
        printf ("\nProcess Completed\n");

    }
    closedir(pnOpenDir);
    return 0;
}
```

But this code is only copying files not the data from the files.

Comment: `fgets` is for text files, not for binaries. A JPEG image is a binary file.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason to write a C program for something that could be done in one line with a shell script?

Comment: Your title is incorrect too. You're copying images from multiple folders/directories into one.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Can you please help me with that line ?